# I am not able to login to my wordpress backend and getting "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page" error

Tags: database, wordpress, error-handling, phpmyadmin, cyber-panel

I am getting this error on my wordpress website "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.". I was trying to delete some unnecessary tables from database and deleted some classified directory pro tables and then this problem occured. i am not able to reupload the tables, i am not able to login to my backend also

we are trying to restore the backup from cyberpanel but we are not able to ssh into vps it is showing access is denied .Please help us solving this problem